# JSP EL private static class inside JSP

Tags: class, jsp, static, el, private

I have following jsp:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Arrays" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html><body>
<%! 
private static class Test {
    private String val2;
    private String val1;

    public Test(String v1, String v2) {
        val1 = v1;
        val2 = v2;
    }

    public String getVal1() {
        return val1;
    }

    public String getVal2() {
        return val2;
    }
};

private static List<Test> ITEMS = Arrays.asList(new Test("1","1"),new Test("2","2"));

%>

<%
    pageContext.setAttribute("ITEMS",ITEMS);
%>

<c:forEach var="item" items="${ITEMS}">
    ${item.val1},${item.val2}
</c:forEach>
</body></html>
```

When TOMCAT executes it - we see exception

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'val1' not readable on type java.lang.String
```

So EL iterates over the collection but for some reason ${item} inside of forEach becomes a String.

However, when you simply change `private static class` to `public static class` - everything works fine.

I undestand it's not a problem, because we have a solution. But I just don't get WHY it DOES REQURE public in this case. JSPs are translated to servlets, so inside translated java code it sees that anyway. Isn't EL just a reflection stuff to get property on object (in our case property is `public`, so EL should be available to get it without reflection modifiers hacking).

If someone knows - please respond. I would very appreciate!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: UPDATE:  
However, in case of `private static class`  
`<c:forEach var="item" items="${ITEMS}">
    ${item.class.name}
</c:forEach>`  
returns `org.apache.jsp.test_jsp$Test`  
So EL doesn't convert ${item} to String...It just cannot take ${item.val1} for some reason...Don't understand it more strongly...

Comment: Put simply: The class and getter need to be visible to BeanELResolver. Thus public, not private.

Answer (score 2):

[JSP](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/HttpJspPage.html)s are translated by the JSP engine into [servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html). EL expressions are evaluated at runtime by the [EL engine](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/package-summary.html).

When `Test` is declared `private` to the JSP its methods are not (by default) visible through introspection to the Expression Language engine.

Here is a snippet from your `forEach` as translated by WebSphere Application Server:

```
   do {
      out.write(_jsp_string4);
      out.write((java.lang.String) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl
         .proprietaryEvaluate("${item.val1}", java.lang.String.class,
                              (PageContext)pageContext, _jspx_fnmap, false));
      out.write(_jsp_string5);
      out.write((java.lang.String) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl
         .proprietaryEvaluate("${item.val2}", java.lang.String.class,
                              (PageContext)pageContext, _jspx_fnmap, false));
      out.write(_jsp_string1);
      int evalDoAfterBody = _jspx_th_c_forEach_0.doAfterBody();
      if (evalDoAfterBody != javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTag.EVAL_BODY_AGAIN)
         break;
    } while (true);
```

EL was designed for use with JavaBeans; beans mandate a public class with a no-args constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have all the answers but I can help you a little. 
Tomcat uses BeanELResolver to define property resolution behavior on objects using the JavaBeans component architecture. Since you are not adhering to JavaBean conventions, the behavior is not defined. You can get a more sensible error message if you use

```
 private static class Test implements java.io.Serializable {
```

which will result in

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'var1' not found on type org.apache.jsp.test_jsp$Test
```

Look at
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/2.1/docs/jsp-2_1-pfd2/javax/el/BeanELResolver.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans

Answer (score 1):

JSP resolves the EL variables using chain of ELResolver's. The following is the EL Resolver chain hierarchy :

- CompositeELResolver

  - ImplicitObjectELREsolver
  - CompositeELResolver

    - PluginELResolver
  - MapELResolver
  - ResourceBundleELResolver
  - ListELResolver
  - ArrayELResolver
  - BeanELResolver
  - ScopedAttributeELResolver

In this hierarchy your `item` will be resolved using BeanELResolver. BeanELResolver  requires the object to follows certain rules to call it as a `Bean`. One such property is, it should have both setter and getter for each property.

The exception you are seeing is because **you dont have the setter defined for the properties in your bean**.